# using loops and if statements in PHP I need to create pattern

Tags: php

In php i need to get this on the screen:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XOHHHHHHHHHHHHX
XHOHHHHHHHHHHHX
XHHOHHHHHHHHHHX
XHHHOHHHHHHHHHX
XHHHHOHHHHHHHHX
XHHHHHOHHHHHHHX
XHHHHHHOHHHHHHX
XHHHHHHHOHHHHHX
XHHHHHHHHOHHHHX
XHHHHHHHHHOHHHX
XHHHHHHHHHHOHHX
XHHHHHHHHHHHOHX
XHHHHHHHHHHHHOX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Sofar I have successfully created this:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XHHHHHHHHHHHHHX
XHHHHHHHHHHHHHX
XHHHHHHHHHHHHHX
XHHHHHHHHHHHHHX
XHHHHHHHHHHHHHX
XHHHHHHHHHHHHHX
XHHHHHHHHHHHHHX
XHHHHHHHHHHHHHX
XHHHHHHHHHHHHHX
XHHHHHHHHHHHHHX
XHHHHHHHHHHHHHX
XHHHHHHHHHHHHHX
XHHHHHHHHHHHHHX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I don't know how to add character O starting from left top corner to the right bottom corner.

There is a code:

```
<?php 

$x = 15;
$y = 15;

for ($i = 0; $i < $y; $i++)
{
    for ($u = 0; $u < $x; $u++) {
        if ($u > 0 && $u < $x-1 && $i > 0 && $i < $y-1) {
            echo "H";
        }
        else {
            echo "X";
        }
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just create a variable like `x` and `y` and if it equals that number you put a `o` instead of an `H`. Then, with the `<br>` you just add 1 to it, as it needs to be extended one each time.

```
<?php 
$x = 15;
$y = 15;
$o = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < $y; $i++){
    for ($u = 0; $u < $x; $u++) {
        if ($u > 0 && $u < $x-1 && $i > 0 && $i < $y-1) {
            if($u == $o){
                echo "O";
            }else{
                echo "H";
            }
        }else {
            echo "X";
        }
    }
    $o++;
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: I hope OP's instructor gives you a good mark for this answer.

Comment: @Sammitch Yes, I do to! Love those marks. But, I know what you are saying, he should do his own homework, I agree.